# Using linear algebra in a multiple choice problem

Tags: linear-algebra

we're working on a project and were wondering how one would go about using linear algebra to compare different choice matrices.
So if you have one matrix where each column is a person, and each row is a certain attribute,
and another matrix with the same structure but different attributes, if I were to compare the "density" of these two matrices what would be the optimal choice? Natural thought is determinant, but this means that for uneven people / attributes arbitrary 0 rows would need to be added to make the matrix square. Any suggestion would be very helpful, or alternatively something to research into. Thanks! More detail can be given if needed.

To clarify a bit more, I'm trying to construct a system where in a set of attributes contribute to two categories (they don't necessarily share any attributes). So let's say our categories are Dine out, and dine in.

Once these attributes are set up for each person, I want to be able to compare their value in some way. So let's say Mary has a child, middle class, and has a coupon. The dine in category would have [0,...,1,..1..] for Mary and the dine out category would have [0,..,1.,,,,,0] (having a child and being middle class would make it more favorable to dine in so that's where those two 1's come in) and the same for the dine out category, having a coupon makes it favorable to eat outside.

Attributes could be: do you have children ? Are you an elderly ? Economic standings? etc.

My inital thought as a solution to my matrix problem is to ignore the matrix and just compute the absolute value of each collection of attributes for each person and then tally up the sum. These sums are then divided by a contributing factor to both categories. So for dining, it would be pricing. (If it's benefitial from an attribute standpoint to dine out, BUT it costs 1000$, your choice should be scaled down).

Comment: You will need to be more specific about what you mean by density and then what you mean by optimal

Comment: Hey Paul just updated as you left the comment, great timing. Does this help?

Comment: The determinant of a matrix with a row of $0$s is $0$, so it is not a good idea.

Comment: Still too broad. An example and what you would do to find the "optimum" might clarify what you are after.

Comment: What is your criteria in an optimal choice? As I understand it, the density of a matrix is the ratio of non-zero elements to zero elements. What does that have to do with comparing two matrices? It sounds like you have two different ways to model whether or not someone would choose to dine out. I am not sure the selection of one over the other has anything to do with linear algebra.

Comment: Very good question, and the more I think about it the harder it is to answer, I guess I'm more so looking for a way in which linear algebra could solve such a problem and what such a model would look like in it's criterium? My own instinctive thought is to tally up each attribute, with associated factors (having a child is more important than having a coupon etc) and then comparing the tally.

Comment: @Bingoboingo I am not an expert on this but it sounds more like a statistical analysis problem than a linear algebra problem. I say this because in linear algebra we study vector spaces and the transformations between them. In your case, it seems like you are more interested in both the accuracy of the model to predict an outcome and, given that a model can predict an outcome, how important are each of the factors in the model.